# How to select the jtable row using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am beginner of Eclipse. I am creating a simple crud system. Successfully load the `JTable` when select the row selected row records will display on the relevant text fields for edit purpose. What I tried so far I attached below.

I have selected event here is select the `JTable` right click event handler mouse clicked but nothing will displayed.

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        df = (DefaultTableModel)table_1.getModel();
        int selected = table_1.getSelectedRow();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(df.getValueAt(selected, 0).toString());
        txtname.setText(df.getValueAt(selected, 1).toString());
        txtmobile.setText(df.getValueAt(selected, 2).toString());
        txtcourse.setText(df.getValueAt(selected, 3).toString());
        btnsave.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

**Screen Shot**
[image]

Comment: Try to set your MouseListener on you jTable (table_1).

Comment: mouse clicked i set to table i attached code above. didn't work

Comment: set table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {   but  didn't work

Comment: when select the row selected row records will display on the relavent textfields for edit purpose. but when select row nothing will displayed

Comment: when i selected the row of the JTable.the  relevent row record didn't pass in to relavent textfields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that clicking right mouse button on a `JTable` does not select the row.**

Does this do what you want?

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class StudCrud implements Runnable, ListSelectionListener {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JTable  table;
    private JTextField  nameTextField;
    private JTextField  phoneTextField;
    private JTextField  addressTextField;

    @Override // javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (selectedRow >= 0) {
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                Object obj = model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1);
                nameTextField.setText(obj == null ? "" : obj.toString());
                obj = model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2);
                phoneTextField.setText(obj == null ? "" : obj.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 0));
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        buttonsPanel.add(saveButton);
        JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");
        buttonsPanel.add(updateButton);
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        buttonsPanel.add(deleteButton);
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        buttonsPanel.add(exitButton);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        form.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Student Name");
        form.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        nameTextField = new JTextField(10);
        form.add(nameTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone");
        form.add(phoneLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        phoneTextField = new JTextField(10);
        form.add(phoneTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("Address");
        form.add(addressLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        addressTextField = new JTextField(10);
        form.add(addressTextField, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        form.add(createButtons(), gbc);
        return form;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTable() {
        table = new JTable(createTableModel());
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private TableModel createTableModel() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"id", "name", "mobile", "course"};
        Object[][] data = {{"1", "suren", "883", "php"},
                           {"2", "asd", "232", "sda"},
                           {"3", "nisa", "8999", "bads"},
                           {"4", "yt", "45", "fgh"}};
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        return model;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Student Crud");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ((BorderLayout) frame.getContentPane().getLayout()).setHgap(10);
        frame.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(createTable(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new StudCrud());
    }
}
```

Use the most appropriate [listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), which, according to my understanding of your problem, is [ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html).

Maybe also read [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as well as [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

This is how it should look.

[image: screen capture]